# How to convert sql nvarChar to formatted decimal

Tags: c#, string.format

I am pulling a value off of the database which is of type nvarchar. My C# program is attempting to format the value but it's not working.

```
    string paymentAmount = null;

    if (dbDataReader["Amount"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
     paymentAmount = string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", dbDataReader["Amount"]).TrimStart('0');
    }
```

The data on the database looks like this:

```
Amount 
0017168
```

After the above code executes the number is 17168. How can I format this number to be 171.68 ?

Comment: You can't use number formatting with a string (which is what `nvarchar` is returned as). Either don't store your numerical data as a string, or parse the data as a numeric type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var amount = decimal.Parse(dbDataReader["Amount"]) / 100;
paymentAmount = string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", amount);
```

Ideally you would store the amount as a numeric value instead of string, but if that's not possible, add some exception handling to make sure it does not blow up at runtime.